# Junit Test valid annotation hibernate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, hibernate-annotations

I've some problem when I try to lunch junit test on my controller. I've coded this controller for my web-app

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/pubblicheaffissioniit/{var0}/{var1}/{var2}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView grazieParameters(@Valid @ModelAttribute("richiestaPreventivoModel") RichiestaPreventivoModel richiestaPreventivoModel, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        logger.info("nome salvato: " + richiestaPreventivoModel.getNome());
........
```

I'm able to launch a junit test with this code

```
BindingResult result = mock(BindingResult.class);
when(result.hasErrors()).thenReturn(false);//or TRUE
```

But I need to test a complete intraction, so I want to call  method above with a void model to testing controller behavior. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not try the Spring MVC test framework: http://blog.springsource.org/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework/

Comment: I've just tried this but it isn't way for my trouble